# Should I say "encouragement to me" or "encouragement for me"?

Tags: prepositions

Are the following correct in grammar, and if not, how can I correct it?

"Thanks for **his encouragement for me to apply** to graduate schools"

"Thanks for **his encouragement to me to apply** to graduate schools"

Comment: Any helpful answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems that "apply to graduate schools" is better. Normally I use "apply for" in "apply for a job/permission", and "apply to" in "apply to a company/university".

Comment: @MarkZar: Okay, it is changed. But do you know the answer to my question? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This needs a bit more context in order to understand if you are speaking about a person in the present, or if you are reporting a person's actions (**his words of encouragement**) in the past. In other words, the sentence is confusing. Please, explain the situation more clearly.

Comment: Okay, the other two copies of this question are now closed: [ELU crosspost](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168114/is-the-following-correct-or-good-in-grammar) - [second copy on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22757/is-the-following-correct-or-good-in-grammar).

Answer (score 4):

I would say:

> Thanks (to him) for encouraging me to apply to graduate schools.

though this sounds a bit weird referring to a third person. Maybe

> I am thankful (to him) for encouraging me to apply to graduate schools.